# Configure native query Jpa

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

If I want to make a respository of an entity, I have it clear. Even if I want only one DTO of this entity.

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {


@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
```

But if I need to create a DTO that is the result of the crossing of 4 tables, and I take fields of 4 (not an Entity) and do it with a Native Query. I do not know how to configure my Repository or what annotations to use:

```
List<MyDTO> myDTO = createNativeQuery(
```

Here I put my configuration file to the DB on which I want to run the Query Nativa

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "elserEntityManagerFactory", 
    transactionManagerRef = "elserTransactionManager", 
    basePackages = {
    "com.xxxx.crm482.repository_elser" })
public class DatabaseElserConfiguration {

@Bean(name = "elserDataSource")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasources.elser")
public DataSource elserDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean(name = "elserEntityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean elserEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
        @Qualifier("elserDataSource") DataSource elserDataSource) {
    return builder.dataSource(elserDataSource).packages("com.xxxx.crm482.domain_elser").build();
}

@Bean(name = "elserTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager elserTransactionManager(
        @Qualifier("elserEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory elserEntityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(elserEntityManagerFactory);
}

}
```